# Computing integrals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, line-integrals, greens-theorem

1. Compute $I := \int_Df(x, y)$ with $f(x, y) := 2y \sin (x)$ and $D$ rectangle with vertices $A := (0, 0)$, $B := (π, 0)$, $C := (π, 1)$ and $D := (0, 1)$.
2. Compute $I := \int_D \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ with $D :=$ {$(x, y) ∈ \mathbb R^2: x^2 + y^2 − 2x ≤ 0$}. Hint: Use polar coordinates.
3. Use the Green theorem to compute $\int_Γ(x^2 + y^2) dx + 2xy \ dy$ with $Γ$ being the boundary of the bounded domain delimiting the curve $y = x^4$ and $x = y^4$ traversed counterclockwise.

My attempts:
1. 
$$
\begin{align}
I &:= \int_D 2y \sin (x) = \int_0^1 \int_0^\pi 2y \sin (x) dxdy \\ 
&= \int_0^1 [-2y \cos(x)]_0^\pi dy = \int_0^1 -2y \cos(\pi) + 2y \cos(0) dy  \\
&= \int_0^1 -2y + 2y dy = \int_0^1 0 dy = c,
\end{align}
$$
where $c$ is a constant. Here I took $\pi = 3.1415$.... And not $\pi$ in radian. Is my answer correct?

2. $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = r$ in polar coordinates. And $x^2 + y^2 - 2x = (x-1)^2 - y^2 - 1$ and so $D$ is the disc of center $(1,0)$ and radius less than or equal to $1$, i.e. $(x-1)^2 - y^2 - 1 \leq 0$ implies that $(x-1)^2 - y^2 \leq 1$.
   Hence, $I := \int_D \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2 \cos(\theta)} r×r drd\theta$, where $r^2 - 2r \cos(\theta) \leq 0$, so $0 \leq r \leq 2 \cos(\theta)$

Then I compute the integral over these boundaries and I get $0$ as an answer. Are my boundaries for $\theta$ and $r$ correct? Or should $-2 \cos(\theta) \leq r \leq 2 \cos(\theta)$

3. $$\begin{align}
   \int_Γ(x^2 + y^2) dx + 2xy dy &= \int_0^1 \int_{y^4} ^{y^{1/4}} \frac{\partial (2xy) }{\partial x} - \frac{\partial (x^2 + y^2) }{\partial y} dxdy  \\
   &= \int_0^1 \int_{y^4} ^{y^{1/4}} 2y - 2y dxdy \\
   &= \int_0^1 \int_{y^4} ^{y^{1/4}} 0 dxdy = \int_0^1 c dy
   \end{align}$$
   where $c$ is a constant. Finally, $\int_0^1 c dy = [cy] _0^1 = c$.

Is this correct?

Comment: One question per post!

Answer (score 2):

1. wrong. $-2y\cos(\pi)=2y$ not $-2y$.
2. wrong. The circle is only in the right half-plane, so the boundaries of the outer integral are $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$.
3. wrong. How did you get the constant $C$ in a closed-form integral?

Comment: +1, Even if the calculation in 1 was correct the integral of the constant zero over $(0,1)$ would exactly be $0$ and not "some constant". An arbitrary constant appears only for indefinite integrals.

Comment: @Hume2 1. You took $\pi$ as radians or as 3.1415... This is where I got confused.                   2. So the boundaries for $\theta$ are $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ and what about the boundaries for $r$.                                                                       3. Is it 0?

Comment: The goniometric functions take radians as parameters unless stated otherwise. If you put there $\pi$ degrees instead, you get something totally different.

Comment: Okay what about 2. The boundaries of $r$ are $0$ and $2cos(\theta)$ and in 3. The integral is 0?

Comment: 2. The boundaries of $r$ are correct but the boundaries of $\theta$ aren't. 3. Yes, the additive constant cancels out in definite integrals.